# Suppose that every vertex of a graph $G$ has degree at least 3. Prove that $G$ contains at least one cycle of length greater than or equal to 4.

Tags: graph-theory

I have seen similar problems posted on this website, but all of them make an assumption I don't understand. Suppose $v_0$ is a vertex contained in a maximal path in $G$. The assumption is made that all of $v_0$'s neighbors also lie in this maximal path. I can accept that each of its neighbors lies in *a* maximal path, but why must it be the same one? Surely the paths $v_1v_0v_3v_4...v_k$ and $v_2v_0v_3v_4...v_k$ can both be considered maximal without having to lie on the same path, right? And if they don't have to lie on the same path, how is the rest of the proof structured?

Comment: It is not at all clear what kind of reasoning you are writing about? Could you please clarify the details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This only makes sense when $v_0$ is assumed to be an endpoint of our maximal path. If $v_0v_1...v_k$ is a maximal path, and one of the neighbors $v_a$ of $v_0$ is not in the path, then the path $v_av_0v_1...v_k$ is longer than $v_0v_1...v_k$, contradicting our assumption that the original path was maximal. Thus all neighbors of $v_0$ must be in the maximal path.